# Не работает flash на ubuntu сервере

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome, flash, vps, vds

Есть юбунту, с которой я успешно поддерживаю связь с помощью x2go. Сам сервер крайне так себе(за 90р)
Характеристики: 1 ядро процессора, 512 Мб оперативной памяти, 10 Гб диска, 1 IP-адрес

Хром я поставил, но использовать я его собирался для флеш игрушки(фармления в ней). Но флеш при этом в хроме не работает и выдает вот это:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос в том, как это исправить, и можно ли вообще на подобном сервере загрузить флэш игру? Если нет, то подскажите на какие минимальные требования и прошу посоветовать где купить сервер с этими параметрами максимально дешево.

Comment: а зачем флеш на сервере? почему не поиграться локально?

Comment: Бота хочется написать а по другому никак

Comment: Флеш перестал поддерживатся браузерами лет как 5

Comment: он будет работать еще до конца этого года